# Como carregar TextBoxFor após onchange de um DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como posso carregar um TextBoxFor  após a escolha de um elemento do DropDownListFor?

Eu carrego o DropDownListFor com uma lista e a parti dessa lista quero filtra um objeto para carregar o saldo de acordo com o id selecionado do DropDownListFor.

```
<div class="linhaInteira">
                <div class="coluna">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContaPagamento.Conta)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ComboBoxDados.Items, Model.ComboBoxDados, "Escolha",
                    new { onchange = "changeSaldo(this);" })
                </div>
                <div class="coluna">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContaPagamento.Saldo)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContaPagamento.Saldo, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Meu JavaScript

```
<script>
    function changeSaldo(sel) {
        alert(sel.value);
    }
</script>
```

Método para carregar o objeto.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ObtemContaPagamento(int id)
{
    var vm = new ConfiguracaoPlanoClienteVm();
    vm.ObtemContaPagamento(id);
    return Json(vm.ContaPagamento.Saldo);
}
```

Comment: Já pensou em fazer um request ajax dentro da função changeSaldo pra buscar os dados através do ObtemContaPagamento?

Comment: não sei como fazer... esse é problema tentei   `$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ClienteConfiguracaoPlano","ObtemContaPagamento")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { id:  21},
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }`

Comment: mas não deu certo

Comment: Mude seu metodo para `[HttpGet]` e tente fazer assim: `$.get('@Url.Action("ClienteConfiguracaoPlano","ObtemContaPagamento")', { id: 21 }, function(data) { alert(data); });`  ... Veja se isso da certo e me fala.

Comment: Teste assim tbm: `$.get('/ClientConfiguracaoPlano/ObtemContaPagamento', { id: 21 }, function(data) { alert(data); });`

Comment: seu ultimo comando funcionou... elabora uma resposta explicando como funciona a rota e os parâmetros.

Comment: Blz @Marconcilio Souza, vou elaborar uma resposta e posto aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de analisar melhor, acredito que o único problema era a ordem dos parâmetros na sua url, por exemplo, você estava fazendo assim:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '@Url.Action("ClienteConfiguracaoPlano","ObtemContaPagamento‌​")', 
    type: "POST", 
    data: { id: 21}, 
    cache: false, 
    async: true, 
    success: function (data) { 
        alert(data); 
    }
});
```

enquanto a url correta seria:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '@Url.Action("ObtemContaPagamento‌​", "ClienteConfiguracaoPlano")',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: 21}),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false, 
    async: true, 
    success: function (data) { 
        alert(data); 
    }
});
```

pois primeiro você deve passar o nome da Action, e depois o nome do Controller.

Repare também que utilizei:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
data: JSON.stringify({ id: 21}),
dataType: 'json',
```

Para que os dados enviados e recebidos sejam por JSON.

Bom, como disse nas mensagens, sugiro trocar o método da sua Action para `[HttpGet]` ao invés de `[HttpPost]`, já que sua requisição somente obtém dados e não altera nada.
Desta forma fica mais seguro, pois o método `[HttpGet]` só aceita a requisição de dados e não a modificação deles no servidor.
Existem casos que vai ser necessário utilizar o `[HttpPost]`, quando por exemplo você tiver que passar como parâmetro da Action, algum dado mais complexo, como por exemplo, uma classe que possua alguma propriedade com algum tipo mais complexo, ou seja, IEnumerable ou alguma outra classe dentro dela. Neste caso teria que utilizar o `[HttpPost]` pois o `[HttpGet]` só aceita parâmetros simples, exmplo: `{ parametro: valor }`.

Neste caso então, sua requisição ficaria desta forma:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("ObtemContaPag‌​amento", "ClienteConfiguracaoPlano")', { id: 21 }, function(data) { 
    alert(data); 
});
```

Outra sugestão que dou, é utilizar uma forma mais amigável de url, como por exemplo:

```
$.get('/ClienteConfiguracaoPlano/ObtemContaPag‌​amento', { id: 21 }, function(data) { 
    alert(data); 
});
```

Ou ainda melhor, para não ter problemas com rotas mais, eu costumo fazer o seguinte.
No meu HTML eu coloco um input to tipo hidden com a url dentro e pego essa url pelo javascript, desta forma acho que fica mais tipado e seguro, desta forma:

No HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="url-obtem-conta-pagamento" value="@Url.Action("ObtemContaPagamento‌​", "ClienteConfiguracaoPlano")" />
```

No javascript:

```
var urlObtemContaPagamento = $('#url-obtem-conta-pagamento').val();
$.get(urlObtemContaPagamento, { id: 21 }, function(data) { 
    alert(data); 
});
```

Desta forma você garante que estará pegando a rota correta e fica mais tipado.

Para entender melhor sobre rotas no ASP.NET MVC, achei [este artigo](https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-as-rotas-no-asp-net-mvc/29861) que explica certinho como funciona de uma forma bem clara.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!